# Jenkins freestyle job for Jenkins backups

Tags: git, jenkins, backup, jobs, ssh-keys

I would like to automate our Jenkins backup process with a Jenkins job. I have created a freestyle job in Jenkins as the job to perform the backup. The goal is to have Jenkins home directory backed up to Bitbucket.

- The job is restricted to run on the master node.
- The Jenkins home directory has been initialized as a git repository.
- The SSH key for the root user on the machine Jenkins is installed on has been added to the list of SSH keys for a Bitbucket account with access to the backup repository.

There is a single build step defined for this job:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins
git add --all
git commit -m "Jenkins automated backup change" || true
git push
```

When I build the job, I receive the following in the console output for the failed job:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/JenkinsBackup/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7036134295202405264.sh
+ cd /var/lib/jenkins
+ git add --all
+ git commit -m Jenkins automated backup change

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <jenkins@c2failover-VirtualBox.(none)>) not allowed
+ true
+ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Warning: this build has no associated authentication, so build permissions may be lacking, and downstream projects which cannot even be seen by an anonymous user will be silently skipped
Finished: FAILURE
```

This seems like a strange error because when I run the `git config -l` command while within the Jenkins home directory the following information is yielded:

```
user.email=jenkins@jenkins.com
user.name=Jenkins Automated Backup
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://git@###.##.##.###:7999/at/jenkinsbackup.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

What may be going on here? The error message provided in the console output for the job is not very clear as to the exact cause of the issue.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are running your Jenkins instance with a different user (e.g. root)?

You can double-check the user.name variable in `http://<yourJenkinsURL>/systemInfo`.

Comment: Wow that's great information! In troubleshooting this issue one of the dead ends I was running into was how to tell what user my Jenkins server is trying to execute the shell commands as. I will investigate now that I have this information and post back with the results!

Comment: As a followup question, how would I go about locating the SSH keys that this user would use when attempting to execute an Git commands? I think the SSH key for that specific user may be the issue here.